# WordPress childtheme not loading any CSS/SCSS

Tags: css, child-theme

I'm using the BigFoot theme and I've made a child theme from this. I've set everything up, my child theme is activated in the wp-admin and everything looks good but for some reason my page isn't loading any CSS.

I'm writing SCSS and converting it into CSS with a build task, when I run the build task it succesfully compiles the SCSS to CSS.

This is my functions.php page

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
//deze code laadt de CSS van de PARENT get_template_directory_uri()
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
//laadt ook de  eigen CSS

wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(  ) . '/css/screen.css', array('parent-style', 'bigfoot-style', 'bigfoot-css'), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
```

}

This is the style.css page

```
/*
Theme Name:   Bigfoot Child
Theme URI:    ***************
Description:  Bigfoot Child Theme
Author:       ***************
Author URI:   ***************
Template:     bigfoot
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License version 3.0
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Tags:         light, two columns
Text Domain:  bigfootchild
*/
```

I've already tried a bunch of solutions I found online but none of them seem to be working. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try removing the forward slash from the stylesheet path? Try this: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/screen.css'`

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didn't do anything

Comment: I do get this warning "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"  when inspecting my page but I don't see anything wrong with my stylesheet link. I've already tried multiple different slash combinations too... <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/screen.css">

Answer (score 0):

after you registered and activated child theme you  should add `wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(  ) . '/css/screen.css', array('parent-style', 'bigfoot-style', 'bigfoot-css'), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));`

in your childs theme functions , i assume by adding `get_stylesheet_directory_uri(  )` to your main theme ytou get wrong path ,
and there is a space in `get_stylesheet_directory_uri(  ) <===` please remove space from brackets.```